# Regular primitive permutation groups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups, permutations, group-actions

Let $G$ be a finite group acting regularly and transitively on a set $X$, so that $|G| = |X|$. Can the action of $G$ also be primitive?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, it's primitive if and only if $|G|$ is prime.

In general a transitive group $G$ is primitive if the stabilizer of a point is a maximal subgroup of $G$. In this case the point stabilizer if the trivial subgroup, which is maximal if and only if $|G|$ is prime.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! With this criterion I am tempted to deduce that it admits a system of blocks of size $n$ for any $n$ dividing $|G|$. It that true?

Comment: No, it admits a system with blocks of size $n$ if and only if $G$ has a subgroup of order $n$ (since the block stabilizer has order equal to the blocksize), which is not necessarily true for all $n$ dividing $|G|$.